Slovenian Alps: actual snow, temperature and weather reports and mesurements, webcameras
I wonder if there are some hydrometeorological data for actual snow in Slovenian Alps (Triglav and other Julian and Kamnik–Savinja Alps). Something like:

Graphs how much snow is on certain areas (e.g. something similar Czech hydrometeorological institute has: https://www.chmi.cz/files/portal/docs/poboc/PR/grafy/snih-lnk.html#labskabouda)
Webcameras (e.g. something similar Czech hydrometeorological institute has: https://www.chmi.cz/files/portal/docs/meteo/kam/)
Weather warnings (general or mountain rescue specific, e.g. https://www.chmi.cz/files/portal/docs/meteo/om/vystrahy/index.html?l=en)

I have found so far I have found https://meteo.arso.gov.si/met/en/warning/ (hydrometeorological institute), https://www.grs-bovec.si/ (mountain resque), but IMHO no weather information there and https://www.hribi.net/spletna_kamera/kredarica/20 (webcamera). Some better resources? I suppose Slovenian would have the best data than some international resources.

My English to Slovene dictionary translates "actual" as resničen, which I suppose isn't what you mean to say.  I think you mean "current," though "current snow" is a bit odd; "current snow conditions" or "current snow cover" or something like that would be better.

This data is measured and collected by ARSO (Slovenian Environmental Agency). Their webpages suffer from a severe identity crisis, which is why you (and even I) had trouble finding what you need. In addition, most of it is in Slovenian only versions of the pages.
The modern "smart" webapp that may prove hard to navigate for non-Slovenian readers but contains or links to everything you need - warnings included:

Webcams starting with Kredarica.
Mountain specific forecast (also with webcams and English translation).
Avalanche warnings
Snowfall amount and snow blanket height

Similar data as above in an older interface (in Slovenian):

Mountain specific forecast
Avalanche warnings
Snowfall amount and snow blanket height (use the links to switch between them)
Weather radar

I guess they expect foreigners to use auto-translation services almost everywhere.
